# Is it possible to click an absolutely positioned psuedo element in Protractor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, protractor

I have an `ng-click` element that has no height of width but is still clickable using the UI since it has an absolutely positioned `:before` element inside of it (an icon). If I try to click the element in protractor it says the element isn't visible, since it has no height or width. I can't find any way to select psuedo elements in Protractor either. Using `browser.actions` isn't easy either as the psuedo element is outside of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. `Protractor/selenium/WebDriverJs click()` doesnt work if an element is not visible. That means if both of these are false - `height>0` `width>0` then `click()` doesnt work. The alternative here is to perform a javascript `click()`

There is beatiful post on the same here - [Clicking an element using javascript vs actions vs webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045218/clicking-an-element-using-javascript-vs-actions-vs-webdriver)

You can do something like this

```
var elm = element(by.css("#myid"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm);
```